# Nautilus shortcut for new blank files?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you create a “new document” keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53202/how-do-you-create-a-new-document-keyboard-shortcut)

Just like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> for folders. Is it possible?

Answer (score 17):

As far as I know Nautilus does not have a shortcut for this but you can create a new empty file using this trick:

Press <kbd>context menu key</kbd> (which opens up right click menu), then press <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>. A new file will be created.

**Edit:**

[Context menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) is next to the win key:

[image]

Comment: Or `Alt`-`F` / `F10`, then `D` and `E`. But it's too long. I'd like a sole chortcut

Comment: This works only if none is selected: when a file is selected the context menu is different. I needed to click on an empty area or unselect or <ctrl+shift+A>. When the window has no empty space, you need to focus (click) on the border of the window first.