# How do you create a "new document" keyboard shortcut?

Tags: nautilus, nautilus-elementary

While I have a nautilus window open I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to create a new folder in the current directory. However there is no default keyboard shortcut for creating a new document. How would I create one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, open gconf-editor and set `/desktop/gnome/interface/can_change_accels` to `true`.  This lets you edit menu shortcuts.

Second, open a terminal and type:
`killall nautilus && UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= nautilus`
This will relaunch Nautilus with the standard (non-Unity) menu bar, because the Unity menu bar doesn't support this feature. (It will respect your changed shortcuts, but it won't let you change them.)

Now, open the file menu, hover the mouse over Create Document > Empty File and press your desired shortcut. Ctrl-Alt-N seems like a decent choice, or you can reassign Ctrl-N. You should see the accelerator hint change in the menu.

Finally, relaunch Nautilus without the `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` variable to get your Unity menus back with the new shortcut.

**Edit**: The solution for newer versions is nearly the same , except you need to use `dconf-editor` instead of `gconf-editor`. You can install the `dconf-tools` package to get dconf-editor.

Also, the `killall nautilus ...` command did not appear to be necessary.

1. Run dconf-editor.
2. Go to `org/gnome/desktop/interface`.
3. Check the box for `can-change-accels`.
4. Open Nautilus and highlight the menu item whose key binding you want to change, either with your mouse or via the keyboard, and press the key(s) you want to use as the shortcut.
5. Don't forget to *uncheck* `can-change-accels` in dconf-editor after you're done.

Comment: `killall nautilus && UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= nautilus` that for some reason did not relaunch nautilus with non-unity menu bar for me. I had to login in classic mode. But worked. :)

Comment: is it possible via a single bash script?

Comment: Anyway to do this in 12.04? I'm getting stuck at step two. No process named nautilus is found.

Comment: For 12.04 see my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/q/88010/

Comment: Appreciate the edit, however if you are using unity, I think it's still necessary to relaunch nautilus with the global menu bar disabled: the hover-and-press-shortcut behaviour doesn't work on the unity menus.

Comment: Not Working on 15.10 : 3rd Step

Comment: This behaviour seems to have been removed in recent versions of GTK3, so we're going to need a new solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal:`gconf-editor`

go to

```
/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands
```

find unassigned command e.g. **command_1**

double click on value and type `/usr/bin/gedit`

next step go to

```
/apps/metacity/global_keybindings
```

select run_command_1 (in this example) , double click on the value and set the preferred shortcut

Logout/Login from/to system

Comment: wouldnt this simply open Gedit?

Comment: this will open new document with gedit, the document must be saved after finishing of work

Comment: not what i wanted. thank a bunch though.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I tried to change the accels by hovering-and-pressing-shortcut but it didn't seem to work. Then it dawned upon me, "Hey, why not use the default accels?!"
And it worked perfectly for me.

So here's how to do it.

1. Press <kbd>Alt + F</kbd> to open the File menu.
2. Press <kbd>D</kbd> to go-to the New Document sub-file menu.
3. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to create a new document.

If you just press it rapid succession, it feels almost like a keyboard shortcut.
Press <kbd>Alt + F</kbd>, then immediately <kbd>D</kbd> and immediately after that <kbd>E</kbd>. Boom. You're welcome.